# How to configure npm watcher for uikit?

Tags: npm, getuikit

guys.-)

I try to configure `npm run watch`- command for less. On uikit documentatiton
write that i can create folder "custom" and less file with my code, example my-theme.less. So, i create:

```
src/custom/my-theme.less file and import uikit theme - @import "../src/less/uikit.theme.less";
```

now question -

1. how npm watcher will know about this file?)
2. and how can I make my file entry point for less compiler?

Comment: Try to format your question accordingly. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: It depends how do you build the theme, probably you want webpack for it and if yes - you have to use proper loader for that. If you want "less" effort, start with gulp and make a gulpfile.js that will compile everything on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

By default, UIKit scripts check for a presence of the "custom" folder automatically, but your path is incorrect.

From [documentation](https://getuikit.com/docs/less#create-a-uikit-theme):

- the file should be in `/custom/my-theme.less`
- you override rules from for example `/src/less/components/card.less`

When you look at those paths, you realize, that `custom` folder needs to be next to `src` folder, not inside it.

Furthermore, if you look inside the build scripts, you will find function named `compile` in `less.js` build script which has paths defined:

1. `paths: ['src/less/', 'custom/']`

So to summurize, if your custom files are in correct folders, they will be processed automatically and all CSS/JS files will be generated with your custom names as well